# unable to retrieve set cookie in a windows store app

Tags: windows, cookies, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am using an `authentication cookie` to enable easy access to a web server in my store app.
Whenever a very first call is attempted to the server, it will set the cookie for me in the response along with other minor info cookies.

I used a `httpcookiecollection class` to iterate through the list of cookies I'd received and to fetch their values.

```
HttpCookieCollection^ cookieCollection = filter->CookieManager-  >GetCookies(resourceAddress);
```

Actually through fiddler I could see 4 cookies set in the response header whereas the list I obtained through the collection has only 3. My important authentication cookie is missing from the list. I want to retrieve its value and use it further.
Can someone please help me in figuring out whats going wrong here?
Thanking you in advance!